# $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}$ and its strange graph

Tags: analysis, logarithms

I was studying exponential growth and noticed that

- $\ln(0.99) \approx −0.010050336$
- $\ln(0.999) \approx −0.0010005$
- $\ln(0.9999) \approx −0.0001 \ldots$, and also
- $\ln(0.9952) \approx −0.004811557$

It seems like $\ln(x) \approx x-1$ for $x\to1$. On a linear scale, this [looks ordinary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%29%2F%28x-1%29+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1). My first question is if this theorem is true and how it is called. It seems only to hold for the natural logarithm, though.

To get more insight, I switched $x$ to a logarithmic scale, i.e.

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln(1-10^{-x})}{1-10^{-x}-1} = -\frac{\ln(1-10^{-x})}{10^{-x}}$$

[This is how it looks](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%281-10%5E-x%29%2F%281-10%5E-x-1%29+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+400).

The exact position depends on the base of the exponentation, which is 10 in this case.

Can someone explain this strange behaviour? Why is there a gap?

Comment: Something something floating point something something precision something.

Comment: Floating Point Arithmetics, I should have known it as a CS student...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can look at the [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) of log to see  (for $x$ close to zero) that:$$\ln (1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$

The interesting patterns you see are all artifacts of computation.  Wolfram Alpha, or whatever software you use, represents numbers in a particular way, and that way leads to rounding errors which get increasingly magnified to produce the graphs you see.

We can calculate your function exactly: $$f(x)=-\frac{\ln (1-10^{-x})}{10^{-x}}=-\frac{-10^{-x}-(\frac{1}{2})10^{-2x}-\cdots}{10^{-x}}=1+(\frac{1}{2})10^{-x}+\cdots\approx 1+(\frac{1}{2})10^{-x}$$

Hence for $x>3$, $f(x)$ SHOULD be indistinguishable from $1$ in terms of a visual plot.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As:
$$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+\cdots\tag{$|x|<1$}$$
So:
$$\ln(x)=(x-1)-(x-1)^2/2+(x-1)^3/3+\cdots\tag{$|x|\in(0,2)$}$$
So for $x-1\ll1\iff x\sim0$:
$$\ln x\approx x-1$$
Also using **L'Hospital**:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1/x}{1-0}=1$$
Or substituting $x=1+y$:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln (1+y)}{y}=1$$
by using the predetermined very common identity of limit of $\ln(1+y)$ over $y$ around zero.